# abstract, virtual and sealed methods in interfaces of C# 8

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

The following interface has no errors in a .NET Core Console application  with C# 8.0

```
interface I
{
    public abstract void f();
    public virtual void g() => Console.WriteLine("g");
    public sealed void h() => Console.WriteLine("h");
}
```

`abstract` prevents adding a definition in interface. `virtual` and `sealed` necessitate a definition in interface. `sealed` prevents an implementation of `h` in derived classes.

Do `abstract`, `virtual` and  `sealed`, when used in interfaces, have any other meaning or applications in current implemented version of C# 8? How and when should they be used in interfaces?

Comment: C# 8 introduced default interface members, something that allows all of those things. An interface can provide an implementation for a member that's used if the implementing classes don't have their own implementation.

Comment: This is useful eg in versioning. Before DIMs, adding a new member to an interface would break all classes that implement it, until they also implemented that method. With DIMs, old classes don't have to change when a new member is added.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that. My question is about  abstract, virtual and sealed. What do they mean in interfaces?

Comment: That's the answer. They are used with DIMs. Their use is described in all articles that describe DIMs

Comment: They shouldn't, if you don't specifically need them. [`public`,] `abstract`, and `virtual` are redundant here. All interface members are virtual (abstract == pure virtual) and prior to C# 8.0, they were always abstract. The abstract/virtual distinction (in a class or, now, in an interface) is simply whether or not there's an implementation. `sealed` prevents the method from being explicitly implemented but not from being implicitly implemented, but that shouldn't be the interface designer's concern.

Comment: Have a look at this (https://www.infoq.com/articles/default-interface-methods-cs8/). Hope it answer your doubt.

Comment: @madreflection what do you mean that "interface members are virtual"?

Comment: Interface members, by necessity, require vtable entries. That's the pre-8.0 view, though, I realize. Now you can have static members and such. But the public members that represent the interface are virtual. A public member that implements an interface member may not, itself, be virtual but when accessed via an interface reference, it's a virtual call.

Comment: @madreflection you said "sealed prevents the method from being explicitly implemented but not from being implicitly implemented". implicit implementation is also impossible with sealed. Trying to do an implicit implementation does not produce an error. But in fact it is not regarded an implementation by compiler. Just an independent function.

Comment: @nano: You're right, my test was improperly done. In that case, `sealed` seems useless because you can't override your `g` method (in an *interface* that implements `I`) any more than you could override your sealed `h` method, and `g` *isn't* marked `sealed`.

Comment: A significant pedagogical problem here was the choice of "virtual". By "virtual" we mean that when you call a method you do not call the method directly; rather you call via some indirect mechanism such as a table lookup. But this is an implementation detail, and a poor description at that. Really what we mean by "virtual" in C# and C++ and other similar languages is *late bound, single dispatch*. That is, the choice of what method to call is determined at runtime -- late -- and the choice is made solely by examining the type of a single argument -- "this".

Comment: If we then apply this to madreflection's statement, it becomes obviously true. "All interface members are late bound single dispatch". They have to be; when you invoke a method of an interface, you don't know *which actual method will be invoked* until runtime, and the exact method you get depends only on the runtime type of *this*. (Leaving aside the new feature of static interface members of course.)

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you for the correction/clarification.

Comment: I didn't intend to make a correction; rather, to explain why it is that this terminology is so confusing and how as language designers we could have made different choices that would have been less confusing. Your statement was correct.

Comment: Oh. Then I thank you for confirming it.

Comment: @madreflection It seems you say these keywords are `useless` in interfaces. By `useless` do mean, that they have only the effects I mentioned in the question and no other effects or applications beyond that?

Comment: @nano: That's correct; those keywords are intended to clarify the meaning. Unfortunately we again have a pedagogical problem. Language designers frequently have to decide whether to make these sorts of redundancies *required*, *optional* or *illegal*, and C# does all three. `private` is optional on a member; if it is omitted, you get it anyway. `public static` is required on a user defined operator; if it is omitted, you get an error. And until recently, `virtual` was illegal on an interface member because it was redundant.

Comment: @nano: Well, I only said that `sealed` is useless, whereas the others are merely redundant. `sealed` does have an effect in that it prevents the implementing class from providing an implementation, as you pointed out. However, that's entirely contrary to the purpose of interfaces and, indeed, default interface member implementations (the default part, specifically). A sealed interface member implemented by the interface could be achieved by an extension method (even pre-8.0) and that would be more meaningful as to its intent. You'd expect to be able to provide an implementation.

Comment: @madreflection: I am currently reviewing the chapter in a C# programming book on these features and I share your concerns; having been absent from the design process for some time now it is not clear to me how the designers weighed the various options and came up with the compromise position they did. I need to do more research on this.

Comment: @EricLippert: Looking forward to that blog post, too.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the proposal:

> The syntax for an interface is relaxed to permit modifiers on its
> members. The following are permitted: private, protected, internal,
> public, virtual, abstract, sealed, static, extern, and partial.
>
> An interface member whose declaration includes a body is a `virtual`
> member unless the `sealed` or `private` modifier is used. The `virtual`
> modifier may be used on a function member that would otherwise be
> implicitly `virtual`. Similarly, although `abstract` is the default on
> interface members without bodies, that modifier may be given
> explicitly. A non-virtual member may be declared using the `sealed`
> keyword.
>
> It is an error for a `private` or `sealed` function member of an interface
> to have no body. A `private` function member may not have the modifier
> `sealed`.